# How to save a html5 Canvas.toDataURl string as a png on a php backend

Tags: php, html, canvas, png

After converting my canvas to a an image source using

```
 canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

and passing it to a php file, how do I save it as a .png image on the server?

Comment: I ended up using
    file_put_contents('test.png', base64_decode(substr($data, strpos($data, ",")+1)));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually very simple, if you have [`allow-url-fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled. PHP supports the `data:` URL scheme then, and automatically decodes base64 and urlencoding.

```
preg_match('#^data:[\w/]+(;[\w=]+)*,[\w+/=%]+$#', $data=$_POST["dataU"])
and
copy($data, "output.png");
```

But you could also just extract the part after the `,` and manually [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/base64_decode) it.