# How to take a screenshot of part of the page to send to Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website that allows users to choose a standard car photo and then overlay different customizations over that image to see how they will look. The clients ultimate goal of this is to be able to screenshot that new image (overlays and all) and post it to the persons facebook wall. I know that the image will have to be stored first so is there a way i can store it in a seperate folder on the site and then use that to upload to facebook? Also is there any method for screenshotting a certain, lets say div, in a browser?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550947/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-website-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial). This will allow you to draw elements and directly save an image. However, you can't simply take a screenshot. This has the potential to create huge security holes.

Comment: Using the canvas element to combine two images seems to be the best way to do this, but after the images are combined how do you save the image in order to be able to share it to facebook?

Comment: This answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957382/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-todataurl-string-as-a-png-on-a-php-backend. Let me know if you run into any issues as I've implemented this before in PHP. You will need some kind of backend scripting to make this work.

Comment: Did you implement this canvas approach with

Comment: Did you implement this canvas approach? Would love to know if it is possible to share a canvas on facebook - see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319958/facebook-like-html5-canvas

Answer (score 0):

There is no scriptable way of getting a screenshot of the user's screen without using a custom plug-in.

Comment: Is there a plugin that is well known and accepted that i can look into?