# Facebook Like HTML5 Canvas

Tags: facebook, canvas

Does anyone know if a user generated HTML5 Canvas could be attached to a Facebook 'Like' action and shared on a Facebook wall?

I guess the canvas would have to be rendered to an `<img>` tag and the id of the tag specified  in the `og:image` metadata?

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's for a 'bike configurator' users configure their bike build by selecting various parts and colours (currently displayed via separate transparent images) we'd like them to then be able to share their configured build to their Facebook wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options as I see it.

(1) Use the [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and in it put a dynamic url which generates the og tags for the configuration the user has chosen.
In the 2nd step of the like button tutorial it generates the og tags for you so you can see what's needed, then just make sure that your server generates those according to what the user configured.
You'll have to make a request from your page to the server when the user finished his configuration so that this will be possible.

(2) Use the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) that comes with the js sdk.
Using that you can specify all of the story fields, for example:

```
var obj = {
    method: "feed",
    picture: "URL_FOR_THE_CONFIGURED_BIKES_PIC",
    name: "My custom bikes!",
    caption: "I just finished building a new pair of bikes",
    description: "My configuration: ....."
};

FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

It is of course possible to mix both options into a third, if you have a specific url per configuration then you can simply:

```
FB.ui({
    method: "feed",
    link: "URL_FOR_THE_USER_CONFIGURATION"
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

And then facebook will extract the data from the og tags in that link.

Comment: So to clarify Facebook would not be able to 'attach' an image rendered in an HMTL5 Canvas on the client - the image would need to be rendered on the server and its URL provided to Facebook?

Comment: Are you referring to a canvas element that you want to then upload as an image?

Comment: I'm wondering if I can use the canvas element to combine the various images into one image that coud be shared to facebook on the client without needing to render or save the image server side.

So - if I save the configuration to a URL which is 'liked' would facebook scrape the rendered canvas image and attach it to the wall post?

My guess is probably not - the image would need to be saved to the server first?