# How I can save the image file generated by canvas tag with heatmap.js?

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas, png

How I can save the canvas heatmap.js generated as an image?

I've been testing with toDataURL (), but I can not.

Save on server.

Answer (score 2):

As garmur commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076791/how-i-can-save-the-image-file-generated-by-canvas-tag-with-heatmap-js#comment16159185_12080033), you can just put the data URL as the source for an `img` element, for example like this:

```
//assume you have the data URL in variable "url"
document.getElementById("myImage").src=url;
```

with an HTML tag like this:

```
<img id="myImage"></img>
```

Then the image will contain a (at least in Chrome it does) PNG version of what was on the `canvas` at the time of the data URL generation.

As a side note: they are actually called [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)'s and not URL's, but the javascript function is actually `.toDataURL()`. Strange stuff.

Comment: How I can save the image to the server?

Comment: Please explain, how do you mean "save image to the server"? Do you mean sending it to the server for it to process the image? I won't be able to help you with that. Please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957382/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-todataurl-string-as-a-png-on-a-php-backend?rq=1) question, maybe it'll help you, maybe it won't. Set up a separate question please if not.

Comment: What do you mean, you get an error saying "failure to complete key code"? That would be strange. Why isw the post incomplete?

Comment: Yes, I went through the link contains only part of the code necessary to perform what I intend. But the key thing is that the canvas does not appear in the code directly but through JavaScript, this has much to do ......

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem?

```
var heatmap1 = h337.create({"element":document.getElementById("heatmapArea"), "radius":25, "visible":true});
var url = heatmap1.get("canvas").toDataURL();
```

seemed to work just fine

Comment: But how do I get the picture?

Comment: the url is a `data:url` base64 encoded string representing a picture. You can upload that string to your server and use a php function to convert the base64 to an image file.

Comment: If all you're looking to do is display the image, then you'll simply want to use the resulting data URL as the src attribute for an img element, or as the CSS background-image in CSS.